# Docksal : How can I enable HTTPS / SSL?

Tags: docker, ssl, https, docksal

I'm using Docksal, but I want to use HTTPS/SSL.

Now I am able to navigate to my site by going to the `https://`-domain, but my browser shows that the certificate is invalid (the certificate is from "Internet Widgits Pty Ltd").

I cannot seem to find something in the documentation on how to enable https. It only states that the web service uses self-signed certificates, but these are not allowed by my system (unlink Valet+ for example, which installs the self-signed certificates for you).

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to enable HTTPS/SSL?

Comment: Posting this link here in case if someone else looking to do the same in the future on Docksal.
https://docs.docksal.io/tools/mkcert/

Answer (score 2):

1. Put your certificates for your project's virtual host into `$HOME/.docksal/certs`. E.g. if your project's virtual host is `example.com` then put CRT and KEY files as:

```
$HOME/.docksal/certs/example.com.crt
$HOME/.docksal/certs/example.com.key
```

2. If you never had `$HOME/.docksal/certs` directory before you will need to do `fin system reset` for `docksal-vhost-proxy` to find it
3. In your project set environment variable

```
VIRTUAL_HOST_CERT_NAME="example.com"
```

4. Restart the project with `fin project restart`

Comment: It still uses default *.docksal sertificate.

Comment: There is a million ways to break something. Check your fin config. If you customly overridden web then it will not work. It should have `io.docksal.cert-name` label on it.
Also you should use Docksal version that supports this.
See in details here https://github.com/docksal/service-vhost-proxy#default-and-custom-certs-for-https

Comment: I have tried with/without web overwriting. Tried to 'mount a folder with certs to /etc/certs/custom'. But unsuccessfully. If it worked for you, could you, please show your config?

Comment: @DimaS I would advice to raise an issue in https://github.com/docksal/docksal and describe your case